# Using properties for styling with a MultiLineString in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using a `MultiLineString` feature with a `properties` object defining a color for each item in the `MultiLineString`. Ex:

**MultiLineString**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": {
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties": {
      "lineProperties":[
        {"color":"#FF6600"},
        {"color":"#6600FF"},
        {"color":"#00FF00"}
      ]
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiLineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When mapped, I want to apply the color based on the index of the `coordinates`. Ex, the first `coordinates` string would have `#FF6600` applied since it's the first in the `lineProperties` array.

Is it possible to use a Mapbox expression to match based on index?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to do that you should just split the MultiLineString out into multiple LineStrings.